# how to get the text that appears anywhere along with Image Path using regex expression in python?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

```
import re
 str_text = "the Image Path is https://ictagrisindh.gov.pk/img/inauguration1.jpg the detail goes here and the url was this and Click here to view the detail goes here"
urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', str_text)
print("Urls: ",":".join(urls))
```

Result is:

```
https://ictagrisindh.gov.pk/img/inauguration1.jpg
```

How to get text that appears everywhere where is at the start of the string and end of string?

Any Help would be Appreciated & thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str_text = "the Image Path is https://ictagrisindh.gov.pk/img/inauguration1.jpg the detail goes here and the url was this and Click here to view the detail goes here"
parts = re.search(r'^(?:(.*?) )?(https?://\S+) (.*)$', str_text)
print(parts.groups())
```

**Output**

```
('the Image Path is', 'https://ictagrisindh.gov.pk/img/inauguration1.jpg', 'the detail goes here and the url was this and Click here to view the detail goes here')
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/4FVUeb/1)

Comment: this code does not work when str_text = 
 "  https://ictagrisindh.gov.pk/img/inauguration1.jpg the detail goes here and the url was this and Click here to view the detail goes here & the Image Path is"

Comment: @Umair: Sure, it doesn't but it's another question, how could you differentiate normal text with partial URL (without `http://`)?

Comment: no the url  is correct i,e https://ictagrisindh.gov.pk/img/inauguration1.jpg but why it did not showing the http://

Comment: @Umair: I see what you mean, see my edit, I've made the first part optional. In order to view the `http` in the comment, surround it with backitcks ````

Comment: @Umair: You're welcome, glad it helps. You can upvote the answer if you want ;-)

Comment: now the string value is str_text="Ulr was this SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4-eb100c432091.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END and click here to view screenshots" can you update the regular expression?

Comment: @Umair: Please, edit your question and add other possible texts expected results, or ask a new question